# Why does Json not recognize MySQL calculated values/columns?

Tags: php, mysql, json

Good morning everybody,

in my php-file I want to get several values from a mysql-database and encode in JSON. The query includes values I calculate within the mysql-Select. But when I call the php-file the calculated values are 'null'. I don't know and don't understand why. Select is correct, because I was able to show the results without JSON on a page. 
Maybe you see a mistake in my code or has an explanation for the habbit.

My code is following:

```
<?php 

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Example php script for fetching data from mysql database
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $host = "localhost";
  $user = "root";
  $pass = "";

  $databaseName = "Boerse";
  $tableName = "prices";

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 1) Connect to mysql database
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //include 'DB.php';
  $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
  $dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 2) Query database for data
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT *
FROM (

SELECT DISTINCT ticker, date_format( date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' ) AS date, concat('$', round( close, 2 )) close, concat('$', round( pxchange, 2 )) pxchange, concat( round( pxpct *100, 2 ) , '%' ) pxpct
FROM (

SELECT
CASE WHEN ticker <> @pxticker
THEN @pxclose := NULL
END , p. * , (
close - @pxclose
) AS pxchange, (
close - @pxclose
) / @pxclose AS pxpct, (
@pxclose := close
), (
@pxticker := ticker
)
FROM prices p
CROSS JOIN (

SELECT @pxclose := NULL , @pxticker := ticker
FROM prices
) AS a
) AS b
ORDER BY date DESC
)inv
LEFT JOIN stocks ON ticker = short
LEFT JOIN stockmarkets ON stockmarkets.id = stocks.stockmarket
WHERE stocks.stockmarket = (
SELECT id
FROM stockmarkets
WHERE marketticker = 'NASDAQ' )
GROUP BY ticker
ORDER BY date DESC");          //query
  $array = mysql_fetch_row($result);                          //fetch result    

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 3) echo result as json 
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

Thank you.

--- Edit: the json-string I get ---
I get following JSON-string:

```
["TSLA","2014-03-22 16:06:40","$55.00",null,null,"5","Tesla Motors, Inc.","TSLA","122590000","1","1","1","National Association of Securities Dealers Automated Quotations","NASDAQ","2"]
```

--- Edit: more detailled explanation what I try to get ---
What I try to get is something like this: http://tradingdesk.finanzen.net/ (on the left of the website, the self-refreshing quotations in the table).

I have an own MySQL table with prices and I want to get the latest prices from this and refresh the website table so it shows the latest prices.

As I already mentioned: I have a static version of this and it works. If I try to refresh with MySQL, Ajax and HTML and PHP and without JSON the values disappear after refreshing. And if I am switching between two or more markets the result is a flicker between the selected markets. It is like the code is handling two values.

--- Edit: code of the page with the problem while using intervals to refresh.

Following two codes describe what I have done before. It shows how I get the data.
Important is how it reacts when I use windows.setInterval:
before the first refresh happens the list shows (example):
FB - Facebook, Inc - $50, -$x, -x%

But it was loading slow. After the refresh I just see
FB - Facebook, Inc - $50

If I switch between the markets, e.g. NASDAQ and NYSE, the #stocks-div is flickering. Without the refresh-function it works very well, but is static.

getuser_exp.php

```
 <?php
if( $_GET["q"] )
{
$q = $_GET['q'];
//$q = 'SP500';

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','boerse');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }


$sql="SELECT *
FROM (

SELECT DISTINCT ticker, date_format( date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' ) AS date, concat('$', round( close, 2 )) close, concat('$', round( pxchange, 2 )) pxchange, concat( round( pxpct *100, 2 ) , '%' ) pxpct
FROM (

SELECT
CASE WHEN ticker <> @pxticker
THEN @pxclose := NULL
END , p. * , (
close - @pxclose
) AS pxchange, (
close - @pxclose
) / @pxclose AS pxpct, (
@pxclose := close
), (
@pxticker := ticker
)
FROM prices p
CROSS JOIN (

SELECT @pxclose := NULL , @pxticker := ticker
FROM prices
) AS a
) AS b
ORDER BY date DESC
)inv
LEFT JOIN stocks ON ticker = short
LEFT JOIN stockmarkets ON stockmarkets.id = stocks.stockmarket
WHERE stocks.stockmarket = (
SELECT id
FROM stockmarkets
WHERE marketticker = '".$q."' )
GROUP BY ticker
ORDER BY date DESC";


$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
    }

echo "<table border='0'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Chng</th>
<th>%</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";

  echo "<td>" . $row['ticker'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['close'] . "</td>";

  echo "<td>" . $row['pxchange'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['pxpct'] . "</td>";

    echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".information").click(function () {
var str = $(this).closest("tr").find("#nr").text(); 

$(document).ready(function() {
//
window.setInterval(function(){      
          $.get("getuser_exp.php",
             { q:str },
             function(data) { $('.stock').html(data);
             } //function data

          );
}, 3000);
//      
   }); //document ready
}); //information click


}); //document ready

//highland charts
    var chart; // global

    /**
     * Request data from the server, add it to the graph and set a timeout to request again
     */
    function requestData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'live-server-data.php', 
            success: function(point) {
                var series = chart.series[0],
                    shift = series.data.length > 20; // shift if the series is longer than 20
console.log(point)
                // add the point
                chart.series[0].addPoint(eval(point), true, shift);

                // call it again after one second
                setTimeout(requestData, 1000);  
            },
            cache: false
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'chart',
                defaultSeriesType: 'area',
                events: {
                    load: requestData
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Live random data'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150,
                maxZoom: 20 * 1000
            },
            yAxis: {
                minPadding: 0.2,
                maxPadding: 0.2,
                title: {
                    text: 'Value',
                    margin: 80
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Random data',
                data: []
            }]
        });     
    });

</script>
</head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

<body>
<script src="js/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="js/exporting.js"></script>
<?
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','boerse');
$sql="SELECT marketticker, marketname FROM stockmarkets";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

?>






<!-- upper navigation -->
<div class="nacon">
 <div class="tr">
  <div class="td"><a href="index.htm">Introduction</a></div>
  <div class="td"><a href="tradingdesk.php?id=1">Stocks</a></div>
  <div class="td"><a href="tradingdesk.php?id=2">Bonds</a></div>
  <div class="td"><a href="tradingdesk.php?id=3">Forex</a></div>
  <div class="td"><a href="wallet.php">Wallet</a></div>
 </div>
</div>



<!-- choosing markets -->
<div class="selection">  
    <div class="markets">
Test
<?
echo "<table>
<thead border='0'>
<tr>
<th>Index</th>
<th>Name</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody border='1'>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td id='nr' class='information'>" . $row['marketticker'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['marketname'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</tbody></table>";
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
$current_time = date('G:i:s');
echo $current_time;
?>


    </div>


    <!-- choosing stocks -->
      <div class="stock" >

      </div>

</div>



<!-- chart -->
<div id="chart" style="width:600px;height:300px;">  

</div>



<!-- depot -->
<div id="depot">  
  <ul id="Navigation">
    <li><a href="einfuehrung.htm">DEPOTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="mehrspaltige.htm">ORDERS</a></li>
    <li><a href="fixbereiche.htm">Fixe Bereiche mit CSS-basierten Layouts</a></li>
    <li><a href="navigationsleisten.htm">CSS-basierte Navigationsleisten</a></li>
    <li><a href="browserweichen.htm">CSS-Browserweichen</a></li>
  </ul>
  <img src="../../../src/logo.gif" alt="SELFHTML">
  <p><a href="../fixbereiche.htm#definieren">zurück</a></p>
</div>



<!-- ordermask -->
<div id="ordermask">  
  <ul id="Navigation">
    <li><a href="einfuehrung.htm">DEPOTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="mehrspaltige.htm">ORDERS</a></li>
    <li><a href="fixbereiche.htm">Fixe Bereiche mit CSS-basierten Layouts</a></li>
    <li><a href="navigationsleisten.htm">CSS-basierte Navigationsleisten</a></li>
    <li><a href="browserweichen.htm">CSS-Browserweichen</a></li>
  </ul>
  <img src="../../../src/logo.gif" alt="SELFHTML">
  <p><a href="../fixbereiche.htm#definieren">zurück</a></p>
</div>



<!-- communication -->
<div id="communication">  
  <ul id="Navigation">
    <li><a href="einfuehrung.htm">DEPOTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="mehrspaltige.htm">ORDERS</a></li>
    <li><a href="fixbereiche.htm">Fixe Bereiche mit CSS-basierten Layouts</a></li>
    <li><a href="navigationsleisten.htm">CSS-basierte Navigationsleisten</a></li>
    <li><a href="browserweichen.htm">CSS-Browserweichen</a></li>
  </ul>
  <img src="../../../src/logo.gif" alt="SELFHTML">
  <p><a href="../fixbereiche.htm#definieren">zurück</a></p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

--- EDIT 
Here is a video link [link](http://youtu.be/ZrGuFkSadVE) which shows the flickering problem.

Comment: Can you post the JSON String that you are getting.

Comment: Of course. I added to my post.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the JSON string? It obviously is working so far :)

Comment: @misterManSam: I want to get the values from MySQL and display in an html table and refresh the values in the table if they change in MySQL. Before I tried to refresh the MySQL-output, but it was flickering and didn't display the new values.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

functions.php

```
//Create a new class - This should be in a separate functions page
class CreateTable {

    public $columnArray; // Change this variable name to the same as the 
                                 // object at the end of getData

    function __construct() {
            $this->getData(); // A new instance of the class will run query in getData
    }

    function getData() {

        // Your query here and remove the for loop

        for($i=1; $i < 6; ++$i) {       
            $column[] =  'column' . $i;     
        }

        $this->columnArray = $column; // Change the object name "columnArray"
                                                  // to whatever you want.
                                                  // this will be your array 
    }

    function displayHTML() {
                    // basic table 
        echo '
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Heading1</th>
                    <th>Heading2</th>
                    <th>Heading3</th>
                    <th>Heading4</th>
                    <th>Heading5</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>';
                            // change "columnArray" to the same as the array object name
            foreach($this->columnArray as $key => $value) {
                echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
            }
        echo '
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>';
    }

}
```

tableGenerate.php - this will be loaded with jQuery

```
include('functions.php');

// Generate a new instance of this class
$display = new CreateTable();

    // Give me my table
$display->displayHTML();
```

displayToUser.php - this is the main page that displays your content. `#stage` will load the table.

```
<div id="stage">

</div>
```

jQuery - obviously ensure that you have the jQuery library connected :)

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#stage').load('tableGenerate.php').fadeIn('slow');
}, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
```

Comment: Hello @misterManSam. Thank you very, very much for your help. Eventually I should explain the problem. My problem was, that I had a working html-table with mysql-data. I wanted to refresh prices.Close, pxpct and pxchange every 5 seconds. I tried. But didn't work. Because after refreshing the 3 values disappeared. So your solution would have the same problem?
To understand what I want I like to show an example: http://tradingdesk.finanzen.net/ On the right are two elements with tables. You see them refreshing often.
Well, I get the values from my own DB, but I want to do like the example.

Comment: You could load php with jQuery. I have updated my answer off the top of my head, but a bit of fiddling and it should do what you want :)

Comment: Thank you for your help.I understand most of your code, but have a problem understanding the first code.
But: I tried the last code, the autorefresh. I want to mention that I tried something similar and I edited my post above with the code used BEFORE Json and describe the problems.
But maybe it is the misunderstanding of your first code why I think it wouldn't help and it is difficult to my old try?

Comment: Oh, it seems I have found one problem/mistake: the last two column values disappeared, you remember? Not because I used the setInterval, but because the tables seems to have too many entries. I deleted all entries and added now. And now it shows everything. It is still flickering, but I know I must focus on the entry-problem and the flickering.

Comment: Flickering/switching by the way means: after i clicked on NASDAQ and then on NYSE I see the results for NASDAQ and than for NYSE and this is doing this way always until I close the website.

Comment: Tell you what. Can you upload a dump of the database? I will create a basic working example with the data.

Comment: This is very nice. Thank you very much. Here is an SQL-Fiddle and I hope it is what you need: [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a80329). If you need any other information please tell me.

Comment: Or should I pass the var to html and output, so there is a steady value?